# AWS Lambda SAM rollback deployment

Tags: aws-lambda

Once a lambda is deploy and incase it has some bad logic in it, using aws Lambda SAM is there a way to rollback deployment?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to rollback to a previous version of the lambda

You can publish a new version of your lambda every time you deploy using sam cli. if you add the "**AutoPublishAlias**" property to your lambda function.

Example:

```yaml
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: cmd/lambdas/hello-world/app.lambdaHandler
      CodeUri: src/
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      AutoPublishAlias: live
      Events:
        CatchAll:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /hello-world
            Method: GET
```

Then anytime you want to rollback you can pick a previous version from the interface
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As of 2021-06-22, there isn't a cli method to "roll-back" a `sam deploy` stack. There is an open issue about it [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/1654).

At the moment, my solution is to ensure that I'm doing a proper release in Git, then I can checkout any previous version, build and deploy (updating the live stack accordingly, not rolling-back per-se.)

Because `sam deploy` is ultimately doing a cloudformation deploy, failure/rollback is always a possibility at the stack level. That also means that you can use aws cli to investigate and manipulate stack deployed via SAM just like any other.